Re-selecting best sales forecasting model each month. Is this overfitting?
One of our teams works on sales prediction, and they run ~10 models each month for each product (+100). Then they use the best fitting model for next period prediction, which may be a totally different model they used for last period.
They also don’t try to model groups of similar products, but create specific models for each state and product.
I see this intuitively very wrong, but can’t justify why properly. Is my intuition right here?

You decide how relevant this is, but I just wanted to point it out: investors in hedge funds vastly underperform the funds themselves by chasing last year's best performers; see e.g. https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/wealth/invest/did-you-earn-less-returns-than-what-mutual-funds-delivered/articleshow/55259939.cms?from=mdr

Forecasting is a mixture of science, engineering and art. There are definitely ways that this approach can go wrong... but equally, there are ways in which many other "reasonable" approaches can go wrong. I would say that this approach is indeed reasonable, and not problematic at first glance.
Of course, there are always ways that might help improving matters. In no particular order:

Are the people that actually consume the forecasts happy? Often the end consumers do not like strong fluctuations between yesterday's forecast for tomorrow and today's forecast for tomorrow.
Does your team do post mortems, i.e., calculate forecasts for all models and after the fact check whether they indeed chose the optimal model? Or indeed analyze how strong the relationship between the holdout ranking and the actual ranking is? This is quite often very weak.
As you write, using groups of products (or states) could be beneficial. Or not. It would definitely be a possible thing to analyze.
Another possibility would be to not choose a single model, but to use an ensemble, by averaging all models' forecasts, possibly after removing some uncompetitive ones first. Model averaging usually improves on model selection. Weighting models differently may help, but surprisingly often doesn't (the "forecast combination puzzle").
Finally, do keep the human factor in mind. Creating and probably curating lots of models, and selecting anew every month, sounds like a lot of work. If the team were to move to a more automated procedure, e.g., by simply averaging rather than selecting models, they might be afraid of making themselves redundant. So depending on your position in the hierarchy, you may want to tread carefully here. It may help to frame this as a way to free up some time to try more ways to improve things.


Thanks Stephan. A lot of good insights and beyond technical. Very appreciated comments.

The obvious way to figure out whether this works (as compared to other strategies) is to compare the forecasts vs. the alternative ideas afterwards (or initially just looking backwards).
A few things I would personally consider, but which may or may not be helpful for the particular problem (usually the way to find out is to try it):

While one can pick a single model out of multiple candidate models, it's often better to combine the predictions of multiple models. That's especially helpful if the models are close in performance so that you're not totally sure which one is best in any case, or if some models work better for certain items. The cost of doing this is a little bit of added complexity, because you often want to combine them using stacking on out-of-fold predictions from cross-validation (or perhaps in a sales forecast task, you'd want to look at past-vs-future splits).
Validation strategy: you say they pick the "best fitting model for next period prediction", but what does best fitting mean?

I'd assume/hope your colleagues have already done a good job here, but I've seen shocking examples of people doing this really badly (e.g. messing up feature building and using future sales from next Tuesday to predict future sales on next Monday, which of course is not something you can do in reality).
It's very important to have a good validation strategy that mimics the actual prediction task. E.g. for predicting future sales from past sales, looking at past-vs-future splits, if you want to predict for the next month, maybe even looking at predicting the same month in the last year? There's many options and it needs careful thinking.
Looking at fit on the data you trained the model on is usually a bad idea. It favors models that can overfit more, tends to "reward" bad feature engineering practices that overfit (like badly done target encoding), does not force you to really only use information that you had available at prediction time etc.


As you suggest there is potentially value in using information over related products, because similar trends may apply (surely barbeques, barbeque charcoal, barbeque sausage, barbeque sauce etc. presumably follow very similar patterns over time...) but will differ a little. How much you can gain by predicting them together (e.g. one model, but product category, product id and other product features are inputs) will depend on quite a few things:

how much patterns are similar (you'd probably not want to predict solar flares, yoghurt sales and waiting times on a hotline from the same model),
whether you have so much data on each product that learning more from other products doesn't really tell you more and whether somehow the structure of the model needs to be different (e.g. some products are very weather dependent, others might be related to particular holidays or weekends or seasonal).
Various model types of ways of getting at whether different products are similar either through lots of features describing them or through internally learnt representations (e.g. neural network embeddings, random effects etc.).


Look at what others have done e.g. in competitions like the M5 competitions on Kaggle. Sales forecasting is pretty popular as a competition on Kaggle and people usually write up their solutions such as here, here, here and so on. Kaggle solutions are often a little over-optimized and over-complex (every last bit of performance on the leaderboard counts, usually at the expense of everything like interpretability, practical usability, runtime etc.), but give you some idea of all the things on can try.


Thank you. I'll meet with them next week and ask them some of the commented questions. Their lead was a CS Researcher years ago, so I'd expect him to be rigorous with the methodology, but worst case I'll just learn more about what they're doing.
